# Realm joining list

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have list 1 which contains ID's (List ticketIDs) and list 2:

```
List<Ticket> myTickets = realm.where(Ticket.class).equalTo("Status", "E").findAll();
```

Now I need to get new list (`List<Ticket> newTickets`) which should contain
the tickets with status E and its ID should be in list 1.

I am able to achieve this by doing :

```
for (Ticket ticket : mytickets) 
        if (ticketIDs.contains(ticket.TicketID))
            newTickets.add(ticket);
```

Is it possible to get newTickets by single query (as using forLoop causing performance issues like scrolling being stuck at some points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [RealmQuery.in()](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Long:A-)?

```
String[] strings = new String[ticketIds.size()];
RealmResults<Ticket> results = realm.where(Ticket.class) 
                   .equalTo("Status", "E") 
                   .in("TicketID", ticketIds.<String>toArray(strings))
                   .findAll();
```

Comment: Sorry for delay..if i using ticketIds.toArray() it is asking to cast to Primitive types... when im casting it is says object cannot be cast to primitive types

Comment: actually ticketIds are list of Integers (List<Integer> ticketIds